# Delete method Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

After trying to create a delete method, I am experiencing the following error:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Some mandatory parameters are missing ("id") to generate a URL for route "movie_delete".") in movies/index.html.twig at line 10.
```

The code I am using:
Twig template:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    {% if movies|length == 0 %}
        There are no movie items available. Add a movie <a href="{{ path('movie_create_form') }}">here</a> to get started.
    {% elseif movies|length != 0 %}
        These are the results: <br />
        <ul>
            {% for x in movies %}
                <li>Title: {{ x.title }}  - Price: {{ x.price }} - <a href="#">Edit</a> - <a href="{{ path('movie_delete') }}{{ x.id }}"> Delete</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        <a href="{{ path('movie_create_form') }}">Add more movie entries</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Delete class:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

use AppBundle\Entity\Movie;

class MovieDeleteController extends Controller
{

    public function deleteAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        if(!$id)
        {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('No ID found');
        }

        $movie = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:Movie')->Find($id);

        if($movie != null)
        {
            $em->remove($movie);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('movies');
    }
}
```

And my routing.yml:

```
movie_delete:
    path:     /movies/delete/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:MovieDelete:delete }
```

Can anyone explain me how I should add a Delete method in Symfony so that I can apply the change in the above written code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've forgot to pass the 'ID' variable to the twig route.

```
<a href="{{ path('movie_delete') }}{{ x.id }}"> Delete</a>
```

Should be

```
<a href="{{ path('movie_delete', {id: x.id}) }}"> Delete</a>
```

In your 'movie_delete' route, you've defined an 'id' parameter. This parameter is required for creating this route. Pass the missing parameter in your twig file and you're done!

In case you're going to work on your 'edit' route as well, keep in mind you will need an 'id' parameter as well. Make sure to pass it in your twig file as you did with the 'delete' route.

See: [This Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#linking-to-pages), Here the additional parameters for the twig routing are explained. In your case 'slug' is replaced by 'id'.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, as you can see I'm new to symfony so these kind of minor things I don't know about routing/linking is something I sometimes didn't look well  enough for.

Comment: No worries, make sure you double-check all available documentation on a subject! There's more than enough Symfony documentation to get you going. And if all that fails, we're here for you!

Comment: I am trying to make one for an edit method aswell. But now I wonder, should I always use a for loop in order to show a variable in the action property of the form tag so it can look like this: `<form action="{{ path('movie_edit_update', {id: x.id}) }}" method="POST">`? Whenever I use `{{ for x in id }}`, the form won't display itself (I pass a variable called `id` from the controller to the template in the array part of the response).

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by 'should I always use a for loop'? If you're looping through your list of movies, you should, yes.

Comment: I am just trying to get the id from my overview page to the edit page. I gave the (edit)controller a parameter `$id` and returned it in an array with the (edit)template. The only thing remaining is showing it in the form again (in the edit template). But my guess is I do not have to use a loop to get that single id in the action property of my form tag on the edit template (I only want to edit one movie at a time, therefor I am using an id). I can't seem to find how the form tag would look like for a single variable instead of something that has to be looped for.

Comment: `<form action="{{ path('movie_edit_update', id: ???) }}" method="POST">` What should I fill the question markers with if I am not using a loop, but just a single value?

Comment: I don't understand where the form is coming from. If you're using the same methods as for delete. You should just reproduce the same link you've created for the delete link. The form in your 'edit' screen should just reference the id that you've passed in your controller. No loops anywhere. Maybe you should post this question to SO with your logic so I can take a better look at it.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't pass the id to the `path()` function. What you should've done is:

```
<a href="{{ path('movie_delete', {'id': x.id}) }}">Delete</a>
```

The `path()` function uses Symfony routing and will throw an exception if you forget to specify required attributes.

Answer (score 3):

In your twig code, change the following line :

```
<a href="{{ path('movie_delete') }}{{ x.id }}"> Delete</a>
```

To :

```
<a href="{{ path('movie_delete', { id: x.id }) }}"> Delete</a>
```

Like this, the route will be generated using `x.id` as the `id` parameter.